# Having problem while copying text data from one txt file to another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file text.txt that contains text data: this is a text file
then I have a test.text that is primarily empty.

```
from sys import argv

script, from_file, to_file = argv

out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write((open(from_file).read()))
```

when I run that code the test.txt file gets copied text from text.txt file and it is:

```
this is a text file਍ഀ
਍ഀ
```

why do I get those rectangular blocks?? 
How to fix it??

Comment: Maybe they are already in `text.txt`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: your `to_file` name should be test.txt and `from_file` should be text.txt when you enter them in the arguments. So you need to enter `python script.py text.txt test.txt`

Comment: thanks @manshu, actually I figured out that I had an empty line on my text.txt file and that was being copied and followed by two ਍ഀ characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the "rectangular blocks" you can see that they contain the rows

```
0A
```

and

```
0D
```

which are the hex representations of  `'\n'`  and `'\r'` respectively.  So the blocks are your editor's way of showing you these characters, which are used in Windows to mark the end of a line in a text file and which are usually invisible.